# How to use Split function and If-Else to split a sentence into 2 lists based on key words

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, split

I'm new to coding in Python. I want to split the sentence in the Sample_text into 2 different lists, based on whether the word is a fruit or a non-fruit word, using an if-else loop.

```
Sample_text = """Blend mangos puree, almond milk, protein powder, peanut butter, and strawberries in a blender until smooth. Serve immediately."""

fruits = ["bannanas","acai","blueberries","strawberries","mangos"]

fruit_words = []
non_fruit_words = []
for word in Sample_text.split(" "):
      if 
      else
```

Comment: `if-else loop` isn't really a thing.

Comment: How do you tell if a word is a "fruit word" or not?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is all you were asking for.

```
Sample_text = """Blend mangos puree, almond milk, protein powder, peanut butter, and strawberries in a blender until smooth. Serve immediately."""

fruits = ["bannanas","acai","blueberries","strawberries","mangos"]

fruit_words = []
non_fruit_words = []
for word in Sample_text.split(" "):
      if word in fruits:
          fruit_words.append(word)
      else:
          non_fruit_words.append(word)
print(f"{fruit_words}\n{non_fruit_words}")
```

Outputs:

```
['mangos', 'strawberries']
['Blend', 'puree,', 'almond', 'milk,', 'protein', 'powder,', 'peanut', 'butter,', 'and', 'in', 'a', 'blender', 'until', 'smooth.', 'Serve', 'immediately.']
```